# Provisioning profile doesn't support the Wireless Accessory Configuration capability

Tags: provisioning-profile, xcode8, external-accessory

After upgrading from Xcode 7.3 to Xcode 8, I'm getting an error:

> Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't
>   support the Wireless Accessory Configuration capability.

May I know how to resolve this?

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: facing the same issue.

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it as "Accepted" so that other people also see that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 21):

You should enable it in apple's developer portal.
Go to "App IDs" and edit your app.
Check the `Wireless Accessory Configuration` checkbox.
Cick `Done`

[image]

Now just regenerate your provisioning profile and rebuild/archive using newly generated profile.

Comment: What if Wireless Accessory Configuration is disabled for the App ID? Wondering how to enable it?

Comment: Worth noting is that this is done in developer.apple.com, NOT appstoreconnect.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

1 apply for rights ： https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension/ 
2 check the Wireless Accessory Configuration checkbox in Xcode
3 selected Wireless Accessory Configuration  when create Provisioning Profile

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Go to the Target -> General -> Signing

Click on Automatically Manage Signing and choose a team Account.

Answer (score -2):

press command+,
enter Accounts
re Download All Profiles.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.