# Appcelerator compilation : Error details: Bundle identifier is missing. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor

Tags: bundle, appcelerator

When I tried to compile my app to test on m y device, I got this message :

[ERROR] Error details: Bundle identifier is missing."AppName" doesn't have a bundle identifier for the Debug build configuration. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor.

I found a lot of answers about this but no solution.

I even found this :
"This issue has been resolved and the result is Titanium does not support managed provisioning profiles. It simply displays an error and fails out. This is because the Xcode project we generate doesn't support managed provisioning profiles. We may fix this in the future and remove this limitation. This "fix" will be released with Titanium SDK 6.0.0."

But I still got the problem

Anyone has a solution ? thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Try to open the Xcode project generated in /build/iphone/ Look for the provisioning profile errors or details. After looking at my issues I was able to notice something very similar to this:

[Provisioning profile doesn't support the Wireless Accessory Configuration capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454412/provisioning-profile-doesnt-support-the-wireless-accessory-configuration-capabi)

I followed their instructions and I made progress on this and I ended packing the app correctly.

Also you should update your Titanium SDK and clean the project.